# Twilio Chat API with React is not working after hosting in on Github

Tags: reactjs, api, twilio, chat

I deployed a simple Twilio chat API to my Github account. After hosting the live chat with Twilio on my Github page. I can see the log-in page but after clicking the Login button it doesn't bring me to the chat room page.

It works fine on my local machine but has an issue on Github. Can someone help me with this issue?

my chat website: https://uraden.github.io/chat-app/

```
> import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import WelcomeScreen from "./WelcomeScreen";
import ChatScreen from "./ChatScreen";

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/chat" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Route path="/" component={WelcomeScreen} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A Twilio Chat application needs a back-end server to generate [Twilio Access Tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) that authenticate your users with the Twilio chat service. GitHub pages does not have a back-end and only hosts static sites. Without an access token, users won't be able to use the chat service.

So, you will either need to deploy the entire application to somewhere else, or host a back-end somewhere else that your GitHub hosted front-end can make requests to.